# Backgroundworkers

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

i know a lot of questions like this get asked, but i stil wasn't able to resolve my problem.
I'm making a help program for networking administrators etc. and when i was implementing a port scanner, i found a problem. As long as it was scanning the ports, i couldnt do anything else, not even cancel it, so i decided to use a backgroundworker. Now, my backgroundworker needs 2 parameters given to it, BUT,every time it finds an open port, it has to add it to my richtextbox. On the bottom of the page u can find my code for the scanner, but i can't get it to send me the port at the time it scans it, only at the very end...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 string host = textBox4.Text;

        int portstart = (int)begin.Value;
        int count = (int)einde.Value;
        progressBar2.Value = 0;
        progressBar2.Maximum = ((int)einde.Value - (int)begin.Value);

        for (int i = portstart; i <= count; i++)
        {

            if (progressBar2.Value == progressBar2.Maximum)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                progressBar2.Value++;
            }


            using (var tcp = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
            {
                var ar = tcp.BeginConnect(host, i, null, null);
                using (ar.AsyncWaitHandle)
                {

                    if (ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500, false))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            tcp.EndConnect(ar);
                            richTextBox1.Text += "Port " + i + " Is Opened" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            //Connect was successful.

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                              richTextBox1.Text += "Connection Refused On Port " + i + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            //EndConnect threw an exception.
                            //Most likely means the server refused the connection.

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Connection timed out.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Text += "End Of Scan";
```

Comment: "i can't get it to work". What is going wrong?

Comment: i can't get it to send me the port at the time it scans it, only at the very end.

Comment: `BeginConnect` without `EndConnect`- not good.

Comment: "tcp.EndConnect(ar); ?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your scanning code into the background worker's `DoWork` event handler. Basically it is a loop. You could also implement the `ProgressChanged` event to show an overall scanning progress. To notify the UI about an open port you found, there's actually only this way:

```
// Invoke the following code in context of UI thread
this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
    // Show the port in UI
});
```

You need to update the UI in the context of the UI thread. For `ProgressChanged` the background worker itself makes sure it is called within the correct context. For all other UI updates, you need to do this yourself using for example above snippet.

---

EDIT: I'm going to add some sample code.

```
// Call DoWork like this:
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<string, int, int>(host, startPort, endPort));

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<string, int, int> portRange = e.Argument as Tuple<string, int, int>;

    for (int i = portRange.Item2; i <= portRange.Item3; i++)
    {
        using (var tcp = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                tcp.SendTimeout = 500;
                tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 500;

                tcp.Connect(portRange.Item1, i);

                this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Port " + i + " Is Opened" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
            catch
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Connection Refused On Port " + i + System.Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, i know all this, but i can't get it to send me the port at the time it scans it, only at the very end., and when i just try to put this.richTextBoc1.text in the worker, it says some cross-thread error

Comment: Well, all of these problems would not occur if you really knew all this. Will add sample code to my answer...

Comment: I mean, i understand what u say, but it doesnt work ;p

Comment: I changed my answer to outline my solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but when i clicked the button, the bgworker didnt start, checked everything, no errors nothing, but still...

Comment: I don't see code in your question that implements a button click, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer again, but i just put your code in the button, and in the background worker i put a console write line, and i noticed the background worker doesn't get started like that :/

Comment: Did you attach the events at all? That's how you start a background worker. If it doesn't work, either the button's click event is not attached or the background worker's event is not attached. Set breakpoints. `Console.WriteLine` is not a reliable way of debugging, esp. in a multi-threaded context.